# incompatible C pointer plus seg faults over structure adoption

Tags: c, pointers, struct, configuration, segmentation-fault

I have a problem which I figure I could solve in a matter of seconds, but I can't seem to figure it out.

What I'm trying to achieve is to create a configuration for my program and save all settings at once in my file without too much overhead.

In the past I could manually create the structure using snprintf to pass the integer into a char* which was previously allocated by memory and directly write that to file, but now instead of that, I would rather use a flat-out structure so that if I want to modify values directly, I can instead of using snprintf and atoi functions to convert strings to numbers and vice-versa.

I use the apr_file functions to open the file as I am writing an apache module.

This is my attempt that failed:

```
typedef struct{
    unsigned int setting1;
    unsigned int setting2;
} allsettings;


void read_a_file(request_rec *r){
    allsettings *arecord;  //compiler didn't complain at this line but might have caused segfault
    apr_file_t *f;
    const int perm=0x0755,ior=APR_FOPEN_READ|0,iow=APR_FOPEN_WRITE|APR_FOPEN_CREATE|0;
    if (apr_file_open(&f,strres,ior,perm,r->pool)==APR_SUCCESS){
        rv=apr_file_gets(arecord,sizeof(arecord),f);
        rv=apr_file_close(f);
    }
}
```

Upon compiling, I received the following error which I'm trying to work out:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'apr_file_gets' from incompatible pointer type
```

However, I got rid of that warning by casting argument 1 with char*.

Is there an easy way I could just load the file into two local integers to the function without having to do any string conversion or allocating extra memory into the function and without receiving a segmentation fault?

Comment: The segmentation fault comes from using an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Not only is `arecord` the wrong type, its also uninitialized and thus indeterminate. Regardless, [a `char*` is expected](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__file__io.html#gaf9513b769c10b09e5f37d6d0b86bdce9), and the second parameter is the maximum fill-potential *including the terminating null char*. That function reads strings through a newline or EOF. You have to do the conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all, arp_file_gets() gets a string from a file. I believe you have to parse what you want from the string you got out.
 There are also somethings you need to care in the posted code segment:
 
1. arecord pointer is not allocated hence the pointer you passed into `arp_file_gets` is an invalid pointer. 
2. In this call: **`rv=apr_file_gets(arecord,sizeof(arecord),f);`**
 I understood that you need to read out 2 unsigned int from the file f. But **`sizeof(arecord) = 4 (bytes)`** as a size of a pointer (not a struct size).

Answer (score 0):

apr_file_gets "read a line from the specified file" ([Apache Portable Runtime - File I/O Handling Functions](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/1.4/group__apr__file__io.html#gaf9513b769c10b09e5f37d6d0b86bdce9).

Upon compiling, you receives the warning because **the implicit cast from type struct* to type char* is not allowed** (or allow just you get a warning). If you want to do that you have to cast it explicitly:

```
rv=apr_file_gets((char*)arecord,sizeof(arecord),f);
```

But, the problem with your code are the followings:

1.) The memory allocation for the record pointer missed. A possible solution is the following:

```
allsettings arecord;
...
rv=apr_file_gets((char*)&arecord,sizeof(arecord),f);
```

2.) But the main problem is that you try to use a file reader method created for character/string reading for binary reading. For example, if in your file is a "1234" string than with apr_file_gets method you will get an integer with value 0x34333231 = 875770417, **not** 1234. To avoid that problem you have to implement a parsing method.